# validation check - dictionary value types

Tags: python, pandera

After converting my csv to dictionary with pandas, a sample of the dictionary will look like this:

```
[{'Name': '1234', 'Age': 20},
 {'Name': 'Alice', 'Age': 30.1},
 {'Name': '5678', 'Age': 41.0},
 {'Name': 'Bob 1', 'Age': 14},
 {'Name': '!@#$%', 'Age': 65}]
```

My goal is to do a validation check if the columns are in string. I'm trying to use pandera or schema libs to achieve it as the csv may contain a million rows. Therefore, I am trying to convert the dict to as follows.

```
[{'Name': 1234, 'Age': 20},
 {'Name': 'Alice', 'Age': 30.1},
 {'Name': 5678, 'Age': 41.0},
 {'Name': 'Bob 1', 'Age': 14},
 {'Name': '!@#$%', 'Age': 65}]
```

After converting the csv data to dict, I use the following code to check if Name is string.

```
import pandas as pd
from schema import Schema, And, Use, Optional, SchemaError

schema = Schema([{'Name': str,
                  'Age':  float}])

validated = schema.validate(dict)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: So how do you process the data, one by one or doing some bulk operation on it ?

Comment: @SandeepRawat hi, i updated my ques! basically, bulk would be better as doing it one by one (row by row) might increase the time it takes to run the code

Comment: Why don't you just remove rows which have row["Name"].isdigit()?

Comment: The answer by @FLAK-ZOSO make sense. Moreover you can use multiprocessing here if you want to improve time complexity, only if its a huge data.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it possible?*

For sure. You can use the `int` constructor to convert that `str`ings to `int`egers if possible.

```
for element in list_:
    try:
        element["Name"] = int(element["Name"])
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

A faster way for doing it would be using `isdigit` method of class `str`.

```
for element in list_:
    if element["Name"].isdigit(): # Otherwise no need to convert
        element["Name"] = int(element["Name"])
```

So that you don't have to enter that `try`/`except` block.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer! some of my datasets might consist a million rows so this method might be inefficient due to the time complexity...

Comment: Ok, let me edit...

Comment: the second code you showed us doesn't work, there are floats and ints too, so it'll give an AttributeError

Comment: ‍♀️sorry, the first one doesn't work either, just need to remove the second for loop, thanks

Comment: loop through element.items()

Comment: I think only the first column needs to be converted. At least that's what I see in the question as the expected result

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO if the column name includes different types like float and boolean, how do I work around it?

Comment: Try/except all the types that you want to convert. Notice that bool should be tried as the last one because it doesn't raise ValueError on non-boolean values.